# Write answer in EditText (math quiz) Game crashes

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Need help with my little math quiz...

When I'm running the emulator app, it crashes when clicking on the EditText (answerTxt).

I want to answer the math question in the editTextbox and after doing that I want to click on the button(button1) to see if it's the right answer. If it is right, I will get 1 point. There will be a new question if I'm answering the question regardless if the answer is right or wrong.

```
package com.ebookfrenzy.mattespelet;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.Random;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class PlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {
    private int level = 0, answer = 0, operator = 0, operand1 = 0, operand2 = 0;
    private final int ADD_OPERATOR = 0, SUBTRACT_OPERATOR = 1, MULTIPLY_OPERATOR = 2, DIVIDE_OPERATOR = 3;
    private String[] operators = {"+", "-", "x", "/"};

    private int[][] levelMin = {
                    {1, 11, 21},
                    {1, 5, 10},
                    {2, 5, 10},
                    {2, 3, 5}};
    private int[][] levelMax = {
                    {10, 25, 50},
                    {10, 20, 30},
                    {5, 10, 15},
                    {10, 50, 100}};

    private Random random;


    private EditText answerTxt;
    private TextView question, scoreTxt;
    private Button enterBtn;
    private ImageView response;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

        question =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        answerTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answertxt);
        enterBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        scoreTxt =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
        response =  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.response);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null)
        {
            int passedLevel = extras.getInt("level", -1);
            if(passedLevel>=0) level = passedLevel;
        }

        random = new Random();

        chooseQuestion();
    }

    private void chooseQuestion(){

        answerTxt.setText("= ?");

        operator = random.nextInt(operators.length);
        operand1 = getOperand();
        operand2 = getOperand();

        if(operator == SUBTRACT_OPERATOR){
            while(operand2>operand1){
                operand1 = getOperand();
                operand2 = getOperand();
            }
        }
        else if(operator==DIVIDE_OPERATOR){
            while((((double)operand1/(double)operand2)%1 > 0) || (operand1==operand2))
            {
                operand1 = getOperand();
                operand2 = getOperand();
            }
        }

        switch(operator)
        {
            case ADD_OPERATOR:
                answer = operand1+operand2;
                break;
            case SUBTRACT_OPERATOR:
                answer = operand1-operand2;
                break;
            case MULTIPLY_OPERATOR:
                answer = operand1*operand2;
                break;
            case DIVIDE_OPERATOR:
                answer = operand1/operand2;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        question.setText(operand1+" "+operators[operator]+" "+operand2);
    }
    private int getOperand(){
        return random.nextInt(levelMax[operator][level] - levelMin[operator][level] + 1)
                + levelMin[operator][level];

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if(view.getId()==R.id.button1) {
            String answerContent = answerTxt.getText().toString();
            if(!answerContent.endsWith("?"))
            {
                int enteredAnswer = Integer.parseInt(answerContent.substring(2));
                int exScore = getScore();

                if(enteredAnswer==answer){
                    scoreTxt.setText("Score: "+(exScore+1));
                    response.setImageResource(R.drawable.tick);
                    response.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //correct
                }
            }
            else {
                scoreTxt.setText("Score: 0");
                response.setImageResource(R.drawable.cross);
                response.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //incorrect
            }
            chooseQuestion();
        }
        else {
             int number=Integer.valueOf(answerTxt.getText().toString()); ;

             if(answerTxt.getText().toString().endsWith("?"))
                 answerTxt.setText("= "+number);
             else
                 answerTxt.append(""+number);
        }
        response.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    private int getScore(){
        String scoreStr = scoreTxt.getText().toString();
        return Integer.parseInt(scoreStr.substring(scoreStr.lastIndexOf(" ")+1));
    }

}
```

and here is the errors...

```
10-13 20:39:05.993 4365-4399/com.ebookfrenzy.mattespelet E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa9d15de0
10-13 20:39:06.974 4365-4399/com.ebookfrenzy.mattespelet E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb4056bb0
10-13 20:39:07.885 4365-4365/com.ebookfrenzy.mattespelet D/Something: = ?
10-13 20:39:07.886 4365-4365/com.ebookfrenzy.mattespelet D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-13 20:39:07.886 4365-4365/com.ebookfrenzy.mattespelet E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.ebookfrenzy.mattespelet, PID: 4365
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "= ?"
    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:525)
    at com.ebookfrenzy.mattespelet.PlayActivity.onClick(PlayActivity.java:167)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

this is the XML file..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.ebookfrenzy.mattespelet.PlayActivity"
    android:background="#815959">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/answertxt"
        android:width="200dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Räkna ihop"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:background="#fcfafa" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/kontrollera_button"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="79dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/answertxt"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Score: 0"
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/answertxt"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/answertxt"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/response"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="result"
        android:src="@drawable/tick"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "= ?"`. I'm not sure why but you have an equals sign and a question mark in your answer box. I would put those in their own box or filter them out then wrap in a `try/catch` and do something if it catches a `NumberFormatException`

Comment: Error caused by this line PlayActivity.java:167. Check yout PlayActivity line 167.

Comment: line 167 is the:
            int number=Integer.valueOf(answerTxt.getText().toString()); ;

dont know what to use instead of it

Answer (score 1):

You app error's because you are trying to parse a String value as a integer

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the problem. I don't know what to use instead of it

Answer (score 0):

Error caused by line 167:

```
int enteredAnswer = Integer.parseInt(answerContent.substring(2));
```

Think you should consider possibility, that user can left editBox empty or enter non-numeric value. For this you should catch NumberFormatException:

```
try {
    int enteredAnswer = Integer.parseInt(answerContent.substring(2));
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    // cannot parse integer, notify about wrong anser
    ..
}
```

Comment: Dont know excatly where to put the code. Tried to switch it with:

        int number=Integer.valueOf(answerTxt.getText().toString()); ;

Comment: but cannot resolve symbol: answerContent

what should i keep and what should I delete? Thx for the help....

Comment: still the same problem....

'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick'

'at com.ebookfrenzy.mattespelet.PlayActivity.onClick(PlayActivity.java:166)' 
Lina 166 is the *int enteredAnswer = Integer.parseInt(answerContent.substring(2));'